# The buffer allocated is insufficient when encoding to Rgba16 UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, rgba, bitmapencoder

I am encoding a Canvas control which contains Textblocks as child using the following code but I get

```
The buffer allocated is insufficient
```

My code

```
using(InMemoryRandomAccessStream ras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
{
    var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
    var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(Textify.CanvasControl);
    var width = renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth;
    var height = renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight;
    IBuffer textBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
    byte[] pixels = textBuffer.ToArray();

    //Encode text to PNG
    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, ras);

    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba16,
                         BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
                         (uint)width, 
                         (uint)height,
                         displayInformation.LogicalDpi,
                         displayInformation.LogicalDpi,
                         pixels);

    await encoder.FlushAsync();
...
```

I know it's the `byte[] pixels` buffer that is no large enough as I want to encode to `BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba16`. I do not encounter the error when encoding to `BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8` or `BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8`

I tried calculating the buffer using the following but it only produce empty white bitmap.

```
byte[] pixels = new byte[16 * width * height];

int index = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
    {
        pixels[index++] = 255;  // B
        pixels[index++] = 255;  // G
        pixels[index++] = 255;  // R
        pixels[index++] = 255;  // A
    }
```

I want to use `BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba16` because I want to improve the image quality. How to do this properly? Thanks.

Comment: *"I want to use `BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba16` because I want to improve the image quality."* - That doesn't make sense. Your render target is 32bpp. Trying to go 64bpp in the encoding phase doesn't miraculously improve image quality. It's still 32bpp, with the size requirements of 64bpp.

Comment: @IInspectable ok fair enough. I might misunderstood the differences between Rgba8 and Rgba16. But how do I improve the PNG encoding quality without going to `BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba16` because the quality isn't that good with my current code.

Comment: PNG is lossless. Whatever goes in comes out. If the quality isn't good, then your input isn't good. The encoded output is an **exact** replica of the input.

Comment: @IInspectable In my situation there's still some lost in quality even though I save in PNG. So saying it will fix everything is not the answer I was looking for because it's not.

Comment: I was looking for options in term of Lumia SDK (in my follow up question), thus the sample code. What you saying is common sense as it appears you have no personal experience in using the SDK.

Comment: Right... and in your [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39383488/1889329) you say: *"Here's the image as seen on my PC screen before it's saved to JPEG"*. And then you post a JPEG (!). There is something terribly broken with your mental model, of how things work. Anyway, I gave you all the information you need to know to look into solutions. I'm out. Good luck, you'll need it.

Comment: Now I see where you are coming from. It's just you. Have a nice day!