# How to improve BlendEffect quality? Lumia Imaging 3.0 & UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, alphablending, lumia-imaging-sdk

I am developing an app that put text into a background image. The textblocks are placed on a canvas control as children and I render the canvas to PNG. Then I use the BlendEffect to blend it with a background image.

**UPDATE**
This post is specifically about chaining effects with Lumia Imaging SDK. Unfortunately one of the person who commented was having a tunnel vision and insist that I must learn about the difference between lossy and lossless image. An opinion as useful as telling a kid how to save an image in Microsoft Paint in my context. In some other comment, [he even arrogantly wish that I must be having tons of bugs in my app and am having some mental problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39368550/the-buffer-allocated-is-insufficient-when-encoding-to-rgba16-uwp?noredirect=1#comment66142076_39368550http://).

I am here to learn about Lumia Imaging and obviously I encountered a person who has no experience with that SDK and insisted on showing off. Then down voted this post to make himself feel better.

With that said, @Martin Liversage was helpful by pointing out that it was not merely JPEG artifacts. I have tried playing with **several chaining steps and options while saving as JPEG and indeed the images came out differently**. While saving as PNG did improve the quality, it is still not what I expect. So I am here asking anyone with personal experience using the SDK about what I can I do in my code to improve my result.

Here's my code

```
private async void saveChainedEffects(StorageFile file)
{
    var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
    var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(Textify.CanvasControl);
    var width = renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth;
    var height = renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight;
    IBuffer textBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
    byte[] pixels = textBuffer.ToArray();

    using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream memoryRas = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        //Encode foregroundtext to PNG
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, memoryRas);

        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                             BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
                             (uint)width,
                             (uint)height,
                             displayInformation.LogicalDpi,
                             displayInformation.LogicalDpi,
                             pixels);

        await encoder.FlushAsync();

        IImageProvider effectBackground;

        if (SelectedEffect.Name == "No Effect")
        {
            effectBackground = imageProcessorRenderer.M_Source;
        }
        else
        {
            effectBackground = (SelectedEffect.GetEffectAsync(imageProcessorRenderer.M_Source, new Size(), new Size())).Result;
        }

        StreamImageSource streamForeground = new StreamImageSource(memoryRas.AsStream());

        //Sharpening the text has unintended consequences to I set to 0d
        using (SharpnessEffect sharpnessEffect = new SharpnessEffect(streamForeground, 0d) )
        using (BlendEffect blendEffect = new BlendEffect(effectBackground, sharpnessEffect, BlendFunction.Normal, 1.0f))
        {
            string errorMessage = null;
            Debug.WriteLine("M_SourceSize (Normalized) {0}", imageProcessorRenderer.M_SourceSize);
            Debug.WriteLine("PreviewSize {0}", imageProcessorRenderer.PreviewSize);

            try
            {
                using (var filestream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                using (var jpegRenderer = new JpegRenderer(blendEffect) { Size = imageProcessorRenderer.M_SourceSize, Quality = 1.0, RenderOptions = RenderOptions.Mixed })
                {
                    IBuffer jpegBuffer = await jpegRenderer.RenderAsync().AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    await filestream.WriteAsync(jpegBuffer);
                    await filestream.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                errorMessage = exception.Message;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
            {
                var dialog = new MessageDialog(errorMessage);
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the image as seen on my PC screen before it's saved to JPEG

[image]

Then when the image is saved to JPG, there's a noticeable reduction in the quality as seen below. Enlarge the image and pay attention to the edges of the font.

[image]

So what are my options if I want to get as close as to the original image quality?

Comment: JPEG is very good for photos but not so much for graphic images with single color areas. Use PNG instead. However, I don't believe that the quality issues that you are seeing are JPEG artifacts. It looks more like sharpening and without really understanding your code or how the two samples relate to the code I do see a `SharpnessEffect` being applied.

Comment: JPEG compression affects the colors of the anti-aliasing pixels the most.  That's noticeable.  If you don't want to lose any quality then don't use JPEG.

Comment: You really, absolutely, positively **must** learn about image encodings. Posting a reference image as a JPEG completely defeats its purpose. All we get to see is a damaged image. If you want to avoid quality degradation, use a lossless encoding scheme (for example PNG's, [as was pointed out in an earlier comment already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39368550/the-buffer-allocated-is-insufficient-when-encoding-to-rgba16-uwp#comment66065762_39368550)).

Comment: @IInspectable Saving as PNG still does not get the result I want. The reason I ask also is because  there's another app that saves as PNG but with better result. Interestingly I do get better result in some situation with JPEG. It's not as simple as don't use JPEG and everything will be perfect.

Comment: We do not know what your issue is, since you don't seem to understand a key concept: Lossy vs. lossless encoding. PNG is **always** lossless, free of any compression/encoding artifacts. You can encode any image and decode it any number of times, it will always reproduce the **exact same image**. If you aren't happy with your results encoded as PNG, then your source is wrong. PNG doesn't change your source image. You need to fix the way you create the image source. Using a PNG is only the final step to conserve image quality (unlike JPEG encoding).

Comment: I was looking for options in term of Lumia SDK, thus the sample code. What you saying is common sense and not helpful.

Comment: *"What you saying is common sense"* - Oh, how I wish. Let's recapitulate: *"Here's the image as seen on my PC screen before it's saved to JPEG"*, followed by a screenshot saved as a JPEG. It doesn't appear that you knew or know now, what *lossless* means, or how to apply lossless transformations. Or even, why losslessness may be important. So much for *"common sense"*...

Comment: I hope you feel better now with your assumptions. Respect.

Comment: There aren't any assumptions. You posted a reference image (presumably *"as seen on [your] PC screen"*), and made sure to destroy it before doing so (by using **lossy** JPEG compression). And you don't appear to understand, why this is a problem.

Comment: Feel free to  make your own assumptions to feel good about yourself sir.

Comment: A downvote? OK he is that kind of person. Noted. Anyway I will share my updated code for the benefit of anyone using LUMIA SDK. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Martin Liversage and @Hans Passant feedback, I've decided to avoid JPEG and save to PNG instead. The artifacts on the edges of fonts mostly gone. I guest now I just have to play with the image sharpening to get the result I want.

**UPDATE**
I still do not get the quality level that I want so it's not simply don't use JPEG and everything will be perfect. Hence the question, how to improve BlendEffect quality.

Here's my code

```
private async void saveChainedEffects(StorageFile file)
{
    var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
    var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(Textify.CanvasControl);
    var width = renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth;
    var height = renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight;
    IBuffer textBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
    byte[] pixels = textBuffer.ToArray();

    using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream memoryRas = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        //Encode foregroundtext to PNG
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, memoryRas);

        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                             BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
                             (uint)width,
                             (uint)height,
                             displayInformation.LogicalDpi,
                             displayInformation.LogicalDpi,
                             pixels);

        await encoder.FlushAsync(); 

        IImageProvider effectBackground;

        if (SelectedEffect.Name == "No Effect")
        {
            effectBackground = imageProcessorRenderer.M_Source;
        }
        else
        {
            effectBackground = (SelectedEffect.GetEffectAsync(imageProcessorRenderer.M_Source, new Size(), new Size())).Result;
        }

        StreamImageSource streamForeground = new StreamImageSource(memoryRas.AsStream());

        //Sharpen the text
        //using (SharpnessEffect sharpnessEffect = new SharpnessEffect(streamForeground, 0.3d) )
        using (BlendEffect blendEffect = new BlendEffect(effectBackground, streamForeground, BlendFunction.Normal, 1.0f))
        using (BitmapRenderer bitmapRenderer = new BitmapRenderer(blendEffect, ColorMode.Bgra8888))
        {


            Bitmap bitmap = await bitmapRenderer.RenderAsync();
            byte[] pixelBuffer = bitmap.Buffers[0].Buffer.ToArray();

            using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
            {
                var pngEncoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);

                pngEncoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, 
                    BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, 
                    (uint)bitmap.Dimensions.Width, 
                    (uint)bitmap.Dimensions.Height, 
                    displayInformation.LogicalDpi, 
                    displayInformation.LogicalDpi, 
                    pixelBuffer);

                await pngEncoder.FlushAsync().AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);

                //Need an IBuffer, here is how to get one:
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    memoryStream.Capacity = (int)stream.Size;
                    var ibuffer = memoryStream.GetWindowsRuntimeBuffer();
                    await stream.ReadAsync(ibuffer, (uint)stream.Size, InputStreamOptions.None).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    string errorMessage = null;

                    try
                    {
                        using (var filestream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                        {                                 
                            await filestream.WriteAsync(ibuffer);
                            await filestream.FlushAsync();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        errorMessage = exception.Message;
                    }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
                    {
                        var dialog = new MessageDialog(errorMessage);
                        await dialog.ShowAsync();
                    }
                }
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

### **UPDATE 2**

I've fixed the issue and would like to share my findings in case anyone is in similar situation. It turned out that it's not so much about saving to JPEG or PNG. While PNG does improve the final image, you have to pay attention to the followings

1. Make sure that the foreground and background image has similar dimensions. Lumia Imaging will stretch the foreground by default to cover the background and the aspect ratio won't be respected.
2. If you need to resize your foreground, do it in `renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync` use the overload that allows you to specify the size.
3. Avoid resizing your foreground using `SoftwareBitmapRenderer` especially when you are working with transparent image before blending. For me this affected my image fidelity and reduced the color range for some reason.

This is how rendered the foreground beforehand which blends perfectly with the background.

```
private async Task<SoftwareBitmap> renderForeground()
{
    RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();

    await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(gridToRender, (int)imageProcessorRenderer.M_SourceSize.Width, (int)imageProcessorRenderer.M_SourceSize.Height);
    var width = renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth;
    var height = renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight;
    IBuffer textBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

    //Get the output into a software bitmap.
     var outputBitmap = new SoftwareBitmap(
         BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
         width,
         height,
         BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

    outputBitmap.CopyFromBuffer(textBuffer);

    return outputBitmap;
}
```